# JBoss 7.1 starting slow

Tags: jboss7.x

I'm using JBoss 7.1 with Eclipse. For my application I need to change `localhost` in properties of JBoss to `0.0.0.0`. After I changed that my server starting about 5-6 min, but in `localhost` mode it takes a few seconds. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the related properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change the host name to an IP address. JBoss AS 7 will try to resolve that in the domain name system. The resulting failures/timeouts will be causing the issues you're seeing - and others too.

If your intention was to allow connections from computers other than the one you are on, you should instead check the "Listen on all interfaces to allow remote web connections" box - you can see it there on your screenshot. See also [this JBoss Community post](https://community.jboss.org/message/614897).

If you genuinely need to change the host name, define a valid hostname with a valid IP address in the domain name system or in `/etc/host` (if you're on a *nix operating system) then use that name in the JBoss configuration. Do not use an IP address, an IP address is not a host name.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I can configure same thing on production sever (on command line interface)? There is no same interface on production.

Comment: Read the community post I linked to, it explains how to do it via the server configuration XML. Also, as per http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com.au/2011/09/jboss-as-702-arc-released.html you can use the `-b` command line option. For more help, Google search for `"JBoss AS 7" bind all interfaces` (yes, with the quotes).